# Are both sentences correct: "What did you react?" | "What did you react to?"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Imagine you have a friend, who had allergic reaction to a food yesterday. And you want to ask what food they reacted to yesterday. Can you simply say?

**- What did you react yesterday?**

Or should you specifically add **"to"**?

**- What did you react TO yesterday?**

Regards,

Comment: Please edit to tell more about why you think the first one is possible. Voting to close as unclear or lacking detail.

Comment: Your first example is not grammatically correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We react,  or we react **to** something.  **react** doesn't take a direct object, which your first sentence has it doing.

> What did you react yesterday? <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

You can also say:

> To what did you react yesterday?